# How to avoid big factory functions everywhere when creating a plugin API?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm designing a plugin API for a game engine. Plugins need to be able to add UI elements to things in the engine. To create a new container and fill it with a simple label when not using the plugin API I would simply do this:

```
Container container = new Container();
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Hello World!";
container.Add(label);
```

However, the Container and Label classes (defined in the GUI component of the engine) aren't accessible directly for plugins and rather go through the plugin API. (because if they were, changes to the GUI module would probably break all plugins depending on that GUI module across versions)

So instead it would start looking like this in a plugin:

```
IContainer container = m_Engine.GUI.ElementFactory.CreateContainer();
ILabel label = m_Engine.GUI.ElementFactory.CreateLabel();
label.Text = "Hello World!";
container.Add(label);
```

Not very pretty. How could I adapt my design so I still have a distinct plugin API separate from the engine itself, while still allowing short nice looking code without factory method calls littered everywhere?

Comment: I should note that c# naming conventions do not use the `m_` prefix and `GUI` should be `Gui` as it is an abbreviation of more than two letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing you could use generics.

```
var label = GUI.ElementFactory.Create<ILabel>()
```

would give you a label and you could also be easily filled by an IoC container like [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac).

Depending on how much effort you're willing to put into your plugin system you might want to consider not having people write plugins in c# at all. They could write them in a dynamic language (like Powershell, IronPython, or IronRuby) and you can have these factory methods be prime aspects of the environment.

Or you can create your own DSL that they use for defining Uis that you interpret and convert into an object graph.

```
labeledInput playerName "Enter Your Name" (50, 50)
labeledInput likes "What do you like?" (100, 50)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the Autofac quick-start right. Looking at it, rather than having the long factory function like, I would instead have to wrap it around a using block. Or can the created object safely be used after the using block has ended?

Comment: @LaylConway I think that you're maybe confused over the concept of an inversion of control container? You typically tell a container that type IFoo is supplied by concrete implementation FooBar. Afterwards when you ask for IFoo it will create an instance of FooBar (along with any dependencies) and give that to you. There's all sorts of benefits and you can usually have them scan an assembly and auto-register types for you. I think you should look up some articles on IoC in general. [Here are some other big ones in the c# space](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ioc)

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions which would serve you as templates. In these functions you could use the factory method calls and you could call these methods so you will not duplicate the factory method calls everywhere.